# weird javascript behaviour while computing backend data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reduce

While filtering data on the backend for some reason the expected response data is wrong but the logs are fine.

basically I have this data inside my mongodb database:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("626a2f00551aa3876e2562eb"),
  username: 'Warren Buffet',
  email: 'pog@gmail.com',
  money: 158,
  trades: [
    {
      coin: 'BTC',
      open: 39341.40429922862,
      amount: 500,
      id: '38b6dbf9-8641-46c0-a2ed-6438dad3515c',
      _id: new ObjectId("626a2ff1551aa3876e2562f2")
    },
    {
      coin: 'SOL',
      open: 99.21601863521198,
      amount: 72,
      id: '71e1034e-1466-4d61-b490-22c096c616c6',
      _id: new ObjectId("626a3e833aa72fb27a936256")
    },
    {
      coin: 'VET',
      open: 0.051906156364343044,
      amount: 100,
      id: '0c1d687c-9efc-4e1f-b1c2-edff3416fc41',
      _id: new ObjectId("626a3e913aa72fb27a93625c")
    },
    {
      coin: 'MKR',
      open: 1678.9138538755535,
      amount: 120,
      id: '18c64d96-ac8d-4c4b-b320-b06ce226e845',
      _id: new ObjectId("626a3ea03aa72fb27a936262")
    },
    {
      coin: 'DOT',
      open: 16.923201350318724,
      amount: 50,
      id: '0fd4f53e-335c-4c66-b99c-47ba1898d954',
      _id: new ObjectId("626a3f023aa72fb27a9364e9")
    }
  ],
  __v: 5
}
```

there are multiple documents like this one.

```
let users = await User.find();

    const data = users.map((user) => {
      
      const money = user.money.toFixed(2);

      let investedMoney = user.trades.map((value) => value.amount);
      investedMoney = investedMoney.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
      console.log(investedMoney); //I get the expected value
      return {
        username: user.username,
        money: money + investedMoney, //the actual response data contains only 'money', not 'money + investedMoney'
        trades: user.trades.length,
      };
    });
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: data });
```

this is my code. The point is gathering username, money (both invested and non invested) and number of trades. For some reason my response data contains only the `money` value, completely ignoring the `moneyInvested`. The weird thing is that I've tried logging out `moneyInvested` and I actually get the expected value. Not sure what's wrong here to be honest.

Comment: Do you mean that moneyInvested is zero? Try return moneyInvested as a fourth key and check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, the money var is a string. Replace

```
 return {
    username: user.username,
    money: money + investedMoney, //the actual response data contains only 'money', not 'money + investedMoney'
    trades: user.trades.length,
  };
```

with

```
 return {
    username: user.username,
    money: Number(money) + investedMoney, 
    trades: user.trades.length,
  };
```